# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show up from fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I am trying to show AutoCompleteTextView from a fragment.  I have three fragments, so i use ViewPager to show the Fragement on MainActivity. I am able to type in the AutocompleteTextview, but the suggestions are not showing up in the mainActivity.
I tried with simple string array, but it doesn't show up. anyone have come across this issue. help me please.
Thanks in advance.

this is my code in the fragment:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String> getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, somestring);
final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview4);    
textView.setThreshold(1);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is my mainActivity callout

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPAger = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Home() ,"HOME");

        viewPAger.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPAger);
```

this is my viewpage adapter

```
package gt.transit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> TabTitles = new ArrayList<>();


        public void addFragments (Fragment fragments, String titles){
            this.fragments.add(fragments);
            this.TabTitles.add(titles);
        }
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TabTitles.get(position);
        }




    }
```

this my XML layout in main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="gt.transit.MainActivity"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:background="#e99d9d"
    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hi all,
thanks for your help. I was able solve the issue.
It's my bad i did not return view properly.

wrong code:

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookmark, container, false
```

corrected code:

```
return v;
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Hi Dalma I posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code for an AutoCompleteTextView dialog fragment

```
public class MyAutoCompleteFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener{
private EditDialogListener mCallback;

public static MyAutoCompleteFragment newInstance(Bundle fB){
    MyAutoCompleteFragment eDialog = new MyAutoCompleteFragment();
    eDialog.setArguments(fB);

    return eDialog;
}

public interface EditDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText, int flag);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (EditDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement onFinishEditDialog");
    }
    this.setCancelable(false);

}

private AutoCompleteTextView mAutoComp;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] lista = getArguments().getStringArray("listagem");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autodialog, container);

    mAutoComp = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autodlg);
    mAutoComp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista));

    //fill the text view with something already typed
    if(getArguments().getString("digitado").length()>0) mAutoComp.setText(getArguments().getString("digitado"));

    getDialog().setTitle(getArguments().getString("titulo"));

    getDialog().setCancelable(false);

    mAutoComp.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    mAutoComp.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    view.setMinimumWidth(500);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
     if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
         mCallback.onFinishEditDialog(mAutoComp.getText().toString(), 0);
         mAutoComp.setText("");
         getDialog().dismiss();
         MyAutoCompleteFragment.this.dismiss();
     }
    return false;
}
```

R.layout.autodialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

   <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autodlg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:completionThreshold="2"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:maxLines="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

How you can call it from activity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Bundle args= new Bundle(); args.putStringArray("listagem", list); args.putString("digitado", typed); args.putString("titulo", title);

MyAutoCompleteFragment frag = MyAutoCompleteFragment.newInstance(args);
frag.show(ft, "autodialog");
```

Don't forget to implement the callback in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText, int flag) {
}
```

You can try in the view pager:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle args= new Bundle();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                args.putStringArray("listagem", listx); args.putString("digitado", typedx); args.putString("titulo", titlex);
                break;
            case 1:
                args.putStringArray("listagem", listy); args.putString("digitado", typedy); args.putString("titulo", titley);
                break;
        }

        return MyAutoCompleteFragment.newInstance(args);
    }
```

And change the MyAutoCompleteFragment to extends Fragment.